# Injecting special cases to Akka Serialization module

Tags: scala, networking, serialization, pattern-matching, akka

I want to add special cases to boost performance of *any* Akka serialization module, i.e. allowing for faster serialization of `Array[Double]` or any primitive types wrapped by the user. Is there a canonical way to allow custom serialization on a per-type basis?

My idea is to add a trait `CanSerialize[T]` which defines methods `serialize(o:T):Array[Byte]` and `deserialize(bytes:Array[Byte]):T`. Is there a way to achieve something like this without losing the benefits of Akka like pattern matching?

**edit** 
I could also be satisfied with Kryo or something else faster than Java's serializer, but there doesn't seem to be any prepackaged jar files for Kryo and Akka 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can register your own serializer for specific types.

```
akka.actor {
  serialization-bindings {
    "[D" = doubleBytes
  }

  serializers {
    doubleBytes = "a.b.YourDoubleArraySerializer"
  }
}
```

Note that `[D` is the class name for `Array[Double]`.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/scala/serialization.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on "[D" ? I don't see how this is Array[Double] ?

Comment: scala> Array[Double](2).getClass.getName
res1: String = [D

Comment: I'm thinking about this scheme: Register a custom serializer which takes Array[Byte] and returns Array[Byte] (i.e. does nothing), and then simply pre-serialize it with my own serialization module. This will work good for my HPC-framework.